# Read/write array values from/into the windows registry WPF

Tags: c#, windows, registry

I want to store array values into the registry and then need to read that values from the registry.

I am getting **string[] IP**  values where I get different Ip addresses in IP variable. and I want to store these array IPs into the windows registry by making the key in local machine.

I am able to store the single value but not getting how to store the **multiple IP values** into the registry. Either **by splitting** or **by making multiple lines**.

Also, i then need to read them as well from the registry.

Please anybody can help me how to do that.

Comment: So, a simple search with "join an array of strings" didn't return the necessary info immediately? I'm very surprised

Comment: show us the codez. [mcve]

Comment: @Sami Kuhmonen:  Thanks, now I am able to store the values but as your statement said you mean I will not be able to read those values easily  after storing that values?

Comment: How to read the splitted values one by one from the registry